# Logo as home link

Tags: html, css, alignment

So, I'll try to keep this short. I am making a navigation and I want my logo to act as the homepage link. Like this:

[image]

However, I'm having trouble with it. Any help would be appreciated!

Code at codepen:

```
`http://codepen.io/aaronmtx/pen/NRYqOm`
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The codepen link is a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Is the codepen for an example or is that the site you are talking about that should be working?

To make a logo a homepage link you just put an href around the image and set the path to "/".

Example:

`<a href="/"><img src="images/example.jgp" /></a>`

In your codepen, the # sign in the links is a standard kind of "change me later with the right path" symbol that just links to the top of the current page. You need to change all of those to be a path. `/` is your root or home page. Anything after that will navigate to other pages.

So you will end up with `/` for the home page, `/services` or `/services.html` etc. depending on your folder and file names.

```
<nav>
    <ul>    
        <li class="nav-logo"><a href="/"><img src="http://baseframe.co/a/img/White-B.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This would make the image a link and upon click it would navigate to the root. Obviously replace your image with the correct logo path.

If that doesn't help, can you clarify by adding your code with file names and folder structure?

Hope this helps!